# Run PHP file in Command Line using PHP script

Tags: php, command-line

I have one simple PHP file which I am running from command line like

```
php my-file.php
```

and its working fine without any issue.
I want run another file when some event happen like below

```
<?php
echo " hello this is sample";
exit();
// I want run another file here after exit command called 
next-file.php
echo "next-file is successfully running";
?>
```

Let me know if someone can give idea how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just create a batch file with 2 calls to 2 scripts

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry! I am learning and does not know how to create batch file and how it will work. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mira, you are a bit short on reasons for doing this. Tell us more and we can probably me more useful help

Comment: actually I have socket connection based file...so I want reload file when sometime connection error arrived in it. I am looking only one line code which can run any php file from php script. Thanks

Comment: Your last comment makes it sounds like you want to keep a single script running, rather than starting a different one. If that's the case then you might be looking for something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `include_once 'next-file.php';` to import and run the code.

Then related to PHP Doc, here is the definition of `exit()`:

> Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

So add this code line into the shutdown function as below:

```
function shutdown()
{
  include_once 'next-file.php';
  echo "next-file is successfully running", PHP_EOL;
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

Be sure to record this function before the `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute a shell command from php using exec()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php